# Freeze, change ... clock in grails/java testing

Tags: grails, testing, timeout, clock, freeze

I am new guy in Grails. And I want to write some integration test to test some session variable timeout. I set 3hr for a cart session variable and I want to create a test to check 3hr later the cart session variable will be destroy because of expiring. Who know any approach to solve this problem? I think I can not write a test to wait for 3 hours.

P/s: Please give me another solution on Java too.

Comment: Could you setup your test environment to override the session timeout value and change it to a smaller value (say 1 min)?

Comment: @nickdos that is a good approach, but I think I won't change my code to test only. The test must be run as real environment. Thanks for advice!

Comment: I this effort valid? You will hang your environment during 3 hours just to check some configuration. @nickdos's approach seems better.